# Application.OpenForms[0].InvokeRequired equivalent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need equivalent for Application.OpenForms[0].InvokeRequired in WinForms for wpf.I tried with

```
var dispatcher = myDispatcherObject.Dispatcher;
if (dispatcher.CheckAccess()) { /* ... */ }
```

but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following extension method:

```
    public static void TryToExecuteOnUI(this Action uiAction)
    {
        var uiDispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        if (uiDispatcher.CheckAccess() == false)
        {
            uiDispatcher.Invoke(uiAction);
            return;
        }

        uiAction();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!!

Comment: You are welcome :)